# Inserting \begin{figure} and \begin{table} enviroments into the \AtBeginDocument{} command

Tags: tables, floats

Is it possible to insert either the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` or the `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` environments into the `\AtBeginDocument{}` command?

Consider the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext, caption}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \begin{figure}[h!]\label{fig:figurelabelexample}%.........Line [1]
        \centering
        \rule{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
        \captionof{figure}{figurecaptionexample}
    \end{figure}%.............................................Line [2]

    \begin{table}[h!]\label{tab:tablelabelexample}%...........Line [3]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ l  c  r }
                        1 & 2 & 3 \\
                        4 & 5 & 6 \\
                        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{tablecaptionexample}
    \end{table}%..............................................Line [4]
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

If the lines marked as [1-4] are commented out, the MWE code complies correctly. However, with them included, my complier complains and throws the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{document}`. Any ideas why `\begin{figure}` and `\begin{table}` would be clashing with `\AtBeginDocument{}`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `\captionof` inside a normal float?

Comment: You could use `\AfterEndPreamble` from the etoolbox package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see why you'd ever want to do this:-) but you *could* do the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext, caption}

\AtBeginDocument{\global\expandafter\let \csname @nodocument\endcsname \relax
    \begin{figure}[htp!]%.........Line [1]
        \centering
        \rule{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
        \captionof{figure}{figurecaptionexample}\label{fig:figurelabelexample}
    \end{figure}%.............................................Line [2]

    \begin{table}[htp!]%...........Line [3]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ l  c  r }
                        1 & 2 & 3 \\
                        4 & 5 & 6 \\
                        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{tablecaptionexample}\label{tab:tablelabelexample}
    \end{table}%..............................................Line [4]
}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I also moved your labels so they work (they have to be after the caption, always).

(Unrelated but I changed your `[h]` option `h` should never be used on its own, LaTeX usually warns and changes it to `ht`)

Comment: Perhaps explain why there is the issue? (Indeed, why is `\everypar` cleraed at a different point to `\let\@nodocment\relax`?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I agree the MWE above is a little weird, but there is some method to my madness; I'm writing a .sty template for some students, which checks the value of a \newtoggle{Flag} defined within the .sty file preamble, and then decides whether to load an example document structure (which includes the example table and figure environments discussed above), or to load the student's own input files...

Comment: @DominicKerr Hmm I'd have a separate example document because then the source and not just the output is an example of what they should do, but it's your document:-)