# Predefined contents at a fixed document location (page number)

Tags: floats, xetex, two-column, preamble, layout

In a two-column XeLaTeX setting, I'm trying to get a framebox to completely take up the full height of one of the two columns in order to display some contents independent of the actual document (think advertisement or impress, etc.). So, the actual document would flow around that box.

But I would like it so that I can declare (in the preamble) the page number where this box is supposed to appear, and the column should always be the *outer* column, i.e., the first column on a left page and the second column a right page. Likewise, the contents of the box should be declared in the preamble.

From a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/592452/28083), I know of techniques to address the issue of targeting a specific page, but I'm scratching my head over the following issue:

> How to make a framebox with fixed contents that starts at the top of
> the outer column and stretches all the way to the bottom, all within
> sth. like `\AtBeginShipout`?

Basically, this is the result I'm after but my knowledge of LaTeX is too limited.

[image: target layout with pre-defined contents on page 43]

To make things worse, I'm stuck on a legacy system with an old version of XeLaTeX (XeTeX 3.141592-0.996-patch1 (Web2C 7.5.6)). On the upside, I know that the actual document will contain no figures or tables.

Comment: "specific page" specified by number or by the content that appears in the text column? (in the former case you know in advance which column is the outer edge)

Comment: By page number.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it even possible?

Comment: oh sure everything's possible you may be able to do it out of the box with xor (which had a force float on to page n feature at one time but im not sure if it does still) or I may hav ean answer on this site doing something similar with the standard latex output routine, I'll look later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much! In the mean time, I will check out xor.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506766/pin-figure-to-page-and-column-in-a-2-column-document.  You can put a framed minipage filling the column.  Note \fboxrule and \fboxsep.  You can also use a tikz node.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Great, that is a very helpful resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this puts the float on the outer edge of page 5.

The trick is to use `[p]` so latex doesn't add it to a text column, then adjust the routine that adds floats to float columns to always fail until you get to the second column of page 5.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\let\zz@tryfcolumn\@tryfcolumn

\def\@tryfcolumn{%
\global \@fcolmadefalse
     \ifnum\c@page<5 \expandafter\@gobble
     \else
\if@firstcolumn
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
\else
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zz@tryfcolumn
\fi
     \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{.8\textheight}
\end{figure}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again, this looks very promising. But how can I move the definition of the figure into the preamble, too?

Comment: @Thomas `\AtBeginDocument{\begin{figure......`

Comment: That doesn't quite work, but luckily you have already shown how to get it done in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202892/28083

Comment: @Thomas ah :-)..